# Why does npm install fetch an old version of the package?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I'm trying to run this command:

> npm install --save react-highlight-words@0.16.0

Which fails with this message:

```
npm install --save react-highlight-words@0.16.0
(node:16708) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: admin_fe@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   dev react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-0" from react-highlight-words@0.16.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-highlight-words
npm ERR!   react-highlight-words@"0.16.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/amitruparel/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/amitruparel/.npm/_logs/2021-10-08T01_17_59_650Z-debug.log
```

However looking at the [github code](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-highlight-words/blob/master/package.json) for this package:

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-0 || ^17.0.0-0"
  }
```

it does seem to support React v17 (which I have)

So I don't understand why is npm not letting me install this package?

Comment: Ah, is there a way to check the package.json file for the package uploaded on npm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the `master` version of `package.json` which may not actually correspond with the one for the 0.16.0 release.

There's no tag for 0.16.0 but you can still view the dependencies for that published version via...

```sh
npm view react-highlight-words@0.16.0 peerDependencies

# { react: '^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-0' }
```

Note that v0.16.0 is [over 3 years old](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-highlight-words?activeTab=versions). The current version on NPM is 0.17.0 which is probably what you want

```sh
npm view react-highlight-words peerDependencies

# { react: '^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-0 || ^17.0.0-0' }
```